# .htaccess URL rewrite ignored

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

.htaccess newbie here.

I have a URL like this:

> example.com/lesson-plans/earth-sciences/show_lesson_plan.php?title=Some_Title&id=6

that I need to be rewritten like this:

> example.com/lesson-plans/earth-sciences/some-title-6

I am using the following .htaccess URL rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^lesson-plans/earth-sciences/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /lesson-plans/earth-sciences/show_lesson_plan.php?title=$1&id=$2&cat=3 [L]
```

However, when I hover over/click on links of the original format (example.com/lesson-plans/earth-sciences/show_lesson_plan.php?title=Some_Title&id=6), they are not being rewritten. I've tried a few different rewrite rules, but nothing works.

How can I make this rewrite work? As far as I know, .htaccess is working on my server and rewrites are permitted.

Comment: ^lesson-plans/earth-sciences/(.+)-([0-9]+)$ /lesson-plans/earth-sciences/show_lesson_plan.php?title=$1&id=$2 [L]

Comment: Rewrite rule cannot go and change your HTML source, that you have to change yourself. Rewrite rule can only rewrite/redirect a URL to another URL.

Comment: @anubhava - I want the rule to rewrite one URL to another. In particular, for SEO. Something like what is achieved here: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Comment: @anubhava - Would this mean that I write my href as the newly formatted rewrite and the server will make up the difference? Now I am more confused than ever! lol

Comment: You should write your href as `example.com/lesson-plans/earth-sciences/some-title-6`

Comment: Thank you. I will give that a shot. Maybe I was close this whole time!

Comment: So, nothing seems to be working. I have made all of the recommendations (and then some) but still find I a 404 error at the end of the redirect. I have even tried placing the .htaccess file in the same directory as the redirection and trimming up the URL. Nada.

Answer (score 2):

You were close

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} title=([^&]+)&id=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^lesson-plans/earth-sciences/show_lesson_plan.php$ /lesson-plans/earth-sciences/%1-%2 [QSA,L,R]
```

Comment: Tried this but it's not working (meaning, the URL stays the same and is not being rewritten). Thanks for trying, though!

Comment: I understand now you call `example.com/lesson-plans/earth-sciences/show_lesson_plan.php?title=Some_Title&id=6`  and want to get `example.com/lesson-plans/earth-sciences/Some_Title-6`. Doesn't it ? I've changed answer with such rule

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I think I will need to step away from this for a couple hours and look at it with fresh eyes to see what I am missing.

Comment: its strange. I added this lines to my htaccess and ask `/lesson-plans/earth-sciences/show_lesson_plan.php?title=title1&id=123456&page=23` was redirected to `/lesson-plans/earth-sciences/title1-123456`

Answer (score 1):

Randomly while lying in bed last night.

You have the rewrite rule back to front. you have to add the rule for the *rewritten* url to turn it back into an ugly one

see: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^lesson-plans/earth-sciences/(.*)-(.+)$ /lesson-plans/earth-sciences/show_lesson_plan.php?title=$1&id=$2&cat=3 [L]
```

so

```
lesson-plans/earth-sciences/some-title-6
```

becomes

```
/lesson-plans/earth-sciences/show_lesson_plan.php?title=some-title&id=6&cat=3
```

Comment: Just gave it a spin. No change.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following code and am posting it as an answer in the event someone else finds this useful:

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ 
>   show_lesson_plan.php?title=$1&id=$2

This will take a url (like this: http://example.com/lesson-plans/earth-sciences/a-cloud-in-a-bottle-i/8923) and run it through this: http://example.com/lesson-plans/show_lesson_plan.php?title=$1&id=$2

*Note that I changed the original URL slightly, opting to break the id out of the title string.*